# R Shiny sourcing UI separately from a file per panel

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build UI from separate files to keep everything organized, but running to porblems when sourcing them to new tap. Here is simple example where I source two files (those can be found below). Sourcing 1 is totally fine, but when I add second source, first page will take UI layout from that, or it goes berserk. Maybe something I'm missing or is this not the way this was meant to work. I think it would keep everything fairly clean. What do I need to do to correctly source layout from a file for each tab?

```
library(shiny)
library(gridlayout)
library(bslib)
library(dplyr)

ui <- tabsetPanel(
  id = "tabset",
  tabPanel(title = "PAGE 1", source(file = "~/page_1.R", local = TRUE)$value),
  tabPanel(title = "PAGE 2", source(file = "~/page_2.R", local = TRUE)$value),
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # DATA:
  x1 <- reactive({runif(input$obs1)})
  y1 <- reactive({runif(input$obs1)})
  
  x2 <- reactive({runif(input$obs2)})
  y2 <- reactive({runif(input$obs2)})
  # PAGE 1
  output$test <- renderPlot({
    plot1 <- plot(x1(), y1())
    plot1
  })
  # PAGE 2
  output$test2 <- renderPlot({
    plot2 <- plot(x2(), y2())
    plot2
  })
  
  output$tbl1 <- renderTable({
    tbl <- tibble(x = x2(),
                  y = y2())
    tbl
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PAGE 1 FILE

```
grid_page(
  layout = c(
    "tabpanel tabpanel",
    "sidebar  plot1"),
  row_sizes = c(
    "10px",
    "1fr"
  ),
  col_sizes = c(
    "150px",
    "1fr"
  ),
  gap_size = "1rem",
  grid_card(
    area = "sidebar",
    card_header("Settings"),
    card_body(
      sliderInput("obs1", "First Page OBS:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)
    )
  ),
  grid_card(
    area = "plot1",
    card_body(plotOutput(outputId = "test"))
  )
)
```

PAGE 2 FILE

```
grid_page(
  layout = c(
    "tabpanel tabpanel tabpanel",
    "sidebar  tbl1  plot2"),
  row_sizes = c(
    "10px",
    "1fr"
  ),
  col_sizes = c(
    "150px",
    "1fr",
    "1fr"
  ),
  gap_size = "1rem",
  grid_card(
    area = "sidebar",
    card_header("Settings"),
    card_body(
      sliderInput("obs2", "Second Page OBS:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)
    )
  ),
  grid_card(
    area = "plot2",
    card_body(plotOutput(outputId = "test2"))
  ),
  grid_card(
    area = "tbl1",
    card_body(tableOutput(outputId = "tbl1"))
  )
)
```

Comment: I believe you should change each file to be wrapped in a single function, then source the files at the start of your `ui` file and call the relevant function for each one.   There's a little more to it but that's the basic plan. This is usually found under the topic of "modular shiny" or "modularising shiny apps" - https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/modules/

Comment: Just noted that reading that link, you don't even need to `source()` them once it's setup properly - if they are in the `R/` subdirectory they will automatically be sourced by the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that modules is way to go, but if someone wants to make this work it is possible with removing `grid_page` from those files and using `fluidPage` and `grid_container`. Then you don't need 'tabset' row there anymore so example would something like this. Doing this on both files, works like I expected it to.

```
fluidPage(
  grid_container(
    layout = c(
      "sidebar  plot1"),
    row_sizes = c(
      "1fr"
    ),
    col_sizes = c(
      "150px",
      "1fr"
    ),
    gap_size = "1rem",
    grid_card(
      area = "sidebar",
      card_header("Settings"),
      card_body(
        sliderInput("obs1", "First Page OBS:", min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500)
      )
    ),
    grid_card(
      area = "plot1",
      card_body(plotOutput(outputId = "test"))
    )
  )
)
```